# Android/Java: Change view from another class?

Tags: android, class, view

There are two classes. MainActivity, in which i set the view, and ClassX from which i want to update a view in MainActivity. ClassX is an AsyncTask called from MainActivity, if that's relevant.

What i want to do is to change the text of a view called mainTextLog. I've declared a global TextView variable, and in the onCreate() method i set it to the view using findViewById().

```
private TextView logger;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    logger = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mainTextLog);

}
```

By now i should be able to change the text from onCreate(), and i can. But since i want to change it from another class (ClassX) i need to create a method for it:

```
public void setLogText(String text) {
    logger.setText(text);
}
```

But it doesn't work. I've tried making logger and the setLogText() method static, but it still doesn't work. The app just crashes.

It's probably pretty easy, but i'm out of ideas.

Comment: I don't have the rep to comment on an answer that was given and I'm sorry that this isn't an actual answer, but note that you cannot create a static method that involves findViewById, as findViewById is non-static. (as far as the answer given by GHz suggests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an AsyncTask you need to set the value in either [onProgressUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onProgressUpdate%28Progress...%29) or in [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29).

You really should read the documentation for [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

You **CANNOT** update the UI from the doInBackground method as it is not run in the UI thread and will give you an exception.

Also, you should post the exception you are getting when the application crashes so we have a better idea what the problem is. But I'd guess you are trying to update the text from the wrong thread.

Comment: Alright, i see. If i were to use onProgressUpdate(), how would i do then?

Comment: If you just want to update the progress after you are done use onPostExecute. If you want to update it as you near completion (for instance to show progress), then you use onProgressUpdate by calling publishProgress: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress(Progress...) . Really you should just read the documentation it explains exactly how to do this.

Comment: Alright, i'll look at it tomorrow (heading to bed now). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've done this plenty in the app im working on, its sort of an MDI type app on the android tablet.

To do what you're asking....

in MainActivity have

```
public static void setText(String txt){
  ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.mainTextLog)).setText(txt);
}
```

then in the child (or calling class) call it like...

```
MainActivity.setText("myTextToShow");
```

That's it... im using android api level 12... If i remember correcty it worked in api level 7 as well though.

Hope this helps...

Comment: That's pretty much the same code i have, except i already have the view stored in logger. It didn't work though.

Comment: Is mainActivity null at the point of trying to set it? if not pop a breakpoint in the method in main to see if its even firing...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that: when you call `setLogText` in another Class X. The MainActivity may not be existing anymore, which makes the `logger` a null reference?